# Best method for storing a decimal number with varying number of decimal places

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We need to store decimal numbers (unit prices) in a database table. The problem is that we need to store and display the same number of decimal places the end-user has given as user input. The maximum number of decimal places is 6. So, for example:

- 1.00
- 9.9999
- 0.123456

To start with, for example, DECIMAL(10,6) seems to always store the maximum number of decimals (6).

MONEY stores a varying number of decimals (2-4), but not more than 4 (and has some other issues, why we do not want to use it).

We know that formatting should always be done on the client that uses the data, but it would be nice, if we could query the data so that the query result would have the correct number of decimals automatically.

We are prepared for adding another column that stores the number of decimal places given by the user, and then use that column to format the data for display, but that sounds a bit complex.

If we add another column, is it possible to format the decimal value directly in the query using that column?

Comment: You should use `DECIMAL(10,6)` if, for no other reason, that you don't a priori know what your data would look like.  Maybe in the future every number would need the full 6 places of decimal precision.

Comment: "We know that formatting should always be done on the client that uses the data," - that's exactly where it SHOULD be done! Don't confuse presentation with representation

Comment: @MitchWheat What I did not mention in the question is that we are already using MONEY and the legacy code (there is a plenty of it, some a bit hard to test) has no formatting. So, "1.01" and "1.0001" both work as expected. When we get rid of MONEY, we need to fix all these places, unless the query result has the right number of decimals in place.

Comment: Never use Money. Period.

Comment: Add another column and store user entered price there as text - then you can calculate using stored decimal values, but show price as user wants. What about money - internally it is decimal too, SQL server just formats it sometimes differently.

Comment: _We know that formatting should always be done on the client that uses the data, but it would be nice, if we could query the data so that the query result would have the correct number of decimals automatically_. Query in what tool? SSMS? Does a user ever intentionally include a trailing 0?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The queries are manually written in vb.net. There might be trailing zeroes that must be kept in the result (so a simple modulo does not work).

Comment: Can I clarify this: a user might enter 3.2 or 3.200, and these values need to be preserved exactly as is? or are both of these always represented as 3.2?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The values should be preserved, i.e., 3.2 and 3.200.

Comment: "The values should be preserved" - then it's possible your design is wrong!

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't think so. Maybe the end user wants to use 3 decimals. Then, it is better to always display 3 decimals. "3.200" and "1.999" rather than "3.2" and "1.999".

Comment: @MitchWheat We would not have the whole issue, if we did not have this legacy code that uses MONEY and works well with the variable number of decimals provided by MONEY. However, that is not the key point. We can do the formatting on the client, if that is the best option, but we still need to a) store the number of used decimals somehow and b) return it in the query in an optimal way.

Comment: Numeric data types store a number. The number 3.2 and 3.200 are the same and will be stored as 3.2. Ths implies that a numeric data type is wrong. This also implies that there is something very peculiar about whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Maybe I am explaining this badly, but the basic problem is a simple one: we need to be able to store and display the same number of decimal places the end-user has given as user input. If the user inputs "3.2", we need to display "3.2". If the user inputs "3.200", we need to display "3.200".  For example. the DECIMAL type has no notion of used decimals, so we need to store that data separately. As one option, I am already considering to store the data simply as text, and then translate that to decimal for calculations.

Comment: The issue is more complicated than my original question. It deals with what we can achieve via computed fields on table level, what can be done for the data on the query level, and how the query result maps to Entity Framework so that we have the data in the optimal format for display. I need to re-formulate the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two soutions I can think of:

1. As you've already mentioned, store it in text
2. Store it in `decimal(19,6)`

   - Store the number of decimals in another field, i.e. `3`
   - Use a calculated column to render the format, i.e. `FORMAT()`

You'd need to reverse engineer the number of decimals though.

This is more complicated but at least you can store the number in a numeric field *and* have SSMS render what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
NumericValue DECIMAL(19,6) NOT NULL,
Decimals TINYINT NOT NULL,
Formatted AS (FORMAT(NumericValue,'#.' + LEFT('00000000',Decimals))) 
)

INSERT INTO MyTable (NumericValue, Decimals)
SELECT 10.2,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1.2,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3

SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Solution #2 is the way to go in our case.

Answer (score 0):

We can use decimal by Storage LAW :

> decimal (1,9)   Storage bytes is   5
>
> decimal (10,19) Storage bytes is   9
>
> decimal (20,28) Storage bytes is   13
>
> decimal (29,38) Storage bytes is   17

About Money :
If you have a sensitive business do not use MONEY.
Money does not need to save us.

For example: We discount the whole invoice. If we want to divide this value for rows in the future, a third decimal place is likely to be created. And if you use Mani this value should be truncated, which will result in a Trending error.

The use of decimals allows the error coefficient to be reduced.

you can know about decimal in [DocMicrosoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Money is internally decimal with 4 places after point. With every fixed precision number you have some corrections to make - like try to divide 10 cents between three rows, equally :)

Comment: @Arvo The use of decimals allows the error coefficient to be reduced. 03.333 cent is better than 3 cent

Comment: I agree that with appropriate decimal you can perform more precise calculations, but mostly those are not needed. With money datatype you get 03.33 cents - but often results need to rounded to full cents (2 decimal places) (03 cents then) and you have to relocate missing cent somewhere :) What I meant that you may got some kind problems with both money and decimal data types; we have used money (in our financial app) for long time and no ill problems encountered. Floats would be disaster :)

Comment: @Arvo In our country inflation is very high and distinct. Our currency has a variety of currencies relative to the dollar, for example we have trouble converting currencies in rare cases. For special cases of high importance we have to use decimals. Of course, I agree with you that Mony is better. For example, for the price of each unit of commodity it is better to use mony, as it solves all the requirements. Or, if specific things are not done, Mony is definitely a better recommendation.